# In ImGUI, is it possible to change the icon at the left of a collapsing header?

Tags: imgui

[image]

I created a date picker using a collapsing header, and I'd like to change the arrow to the left if possible.

Is there a concise way to do this? Or do I have to like, remake the whole collapsing header item from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is rather primitive, Ive been trying to figure out this, too. I was looking through the imgui_widgets.cpp file, specifically the CollapsingHeader method. If you want to ***Permanently*** remove this, you can go to the ImGui::TreeNodeBehaviour Method, and comment out these red-bracketed lines:
[Removal Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3wrc.png)

Where the arrow is, you can tab back the line. This will, again, permanently remove the arrow or bullet functionality from the entire file, but it will work. Im sure theres a dynamic way to do it that Im not sure of, Im relatively new to this library.